# Why does .topBarLeading crash mac catalyst app

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I am trying to add a button to the very left of the toolbar on all platforms. Here is my code:

```
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button(action : {
                    // there is more stuff here, but i don't think it's relevant
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }){
                    Label("Back", systemImage: "chevron.left")
                }
                .padding([.leading])
            }
        }
```

On iOS this works perfectly, but on macOS, I get the following error as soon as I open this view: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`. The app then crashes. I tried using `.navigationBarLeading` instead of `.topBarLeading`, which apparently will soon be deprecated on iOS. This still works on iOS as expected and doesn't crash the macOS app, but on macOS, the icon is still all the way on the right.

Comment: Have you tried building your SwiftUI project as a native macOS app instead of using Mac Catalyst?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, but on iOS, since 17 beta came out.

I fixed it by using `placement: .cancellationAction` and `placement: .primaryAction` instead. Not sure if this will fix your problem on macOS though, but it may work

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why it crash exactly, but when building with `Release` configuration it works fine and won't crash.